# z-index for pseudo element doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create breadcrumbs but unfortunately z-index doesn't work.I tried higher values as well as overriding with !important. Here's my code:

```css
li.breadcr {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #0095c4;
  margin: 0 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 900000;
}
li.breadcr::before {
  content: '' !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: .9em !important;
  left: -8em !important;
  width: 10em !important;
  height: .2em !important;
  background: #0095c4 !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
li.breadcr:first-child::before {
  display: none !important;
}
.active {
  background: #0095c4;
}
.active ~ li.breadcr {
  background: #badae4 !important;
}
.active ~ li.breadcr::before {
  background: #badae4 !important;
}
ul.sub {
  list-style: none;
}
li.sub02 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: TeX Gyre Heros, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="breadcr">1</li>
  <li class="active breadcr">2</li>
  <li class="breadcr">3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub">
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 25px;"><b>File or link</b>
  </li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 53px;"><b>Category</b>
  </li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 50px;"><b>Comments</b>
    <li>
</ul>
```

The code worked on separate html page but when I integrated it with new website the lines vanished.What values for z-index would work so the lines are below circles instead above?
Any suggestions are much appreciated.
Many thanks in advance,
Neko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `z-index` in `ul` instead of `li`, and make sure that the `ul` is not `position: static;`:

```css
ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 900000;
}
li.breadcr {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #0095c4;
  margin: 0 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
li.breadcr::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -8em;
  width: 10em;
  height: .2em;
  background: #0095c4;
  z-index: -1;
}
li.breadcr:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}
.active {
  background: #0095c4;
}
.active ~ li.breadcr {
  background: #badae4;
}
.active ~ li.breadcr::before {
  background: #badae4;
}
ul.sub {
  list-style: none;
}
li.sub02 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: TeX Gyre Heros, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul class="breadcr">
  <li class="breadcr">1</li>
  <li class="active breadcr">2</li>
  <li class="breadcr">3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub">
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 25px;"><b>File or link</b>
  </li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 53px;"><b>Category</b>
  </li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 50px;"><b>Comments</b>
    <li>
</ul>
```

**Eplanation:**

Elements with a `z-index` can no break trough ancestors with a `z-index`. i.e. a child with `z-index: -100` can not be behind his parent with `z-index: 1000`.

Note that `z-index` only work on elements where `position` is not `static` (default value).

Comment: I tried z-index for ul and the lines still aren't visible @Andy Tschiersh

Comment: I have updatet my answer. The `ul` must be `position: relative` (or absolute or fixed, but non static)

Comment: I've added position relative and the lines are still above circles: https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Form/index03.html @Andy Tschiersch

Comment: Add `z-index: -1` to your pseudo elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
  li.breadcr {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #0095c4;
  margin: 0 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li.breadcr::before{
  content: '' !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: .9em !important;
  left: -8em !important;
width: 10em !important;
  height: .2em !important;
  background: #0095c4 !important;
  z-index: -1
}


li.breadcr:first-child::before {
  display: none !important;
}

.active {
  background: #0095c4;
}

.active ~ li.breadcr {
  background: #badae4 !important;
}

.active ~ li.breadcr::before {
  background: #badae4 !important;
}
ul.sub{
list-style: none;
}
li.sub02{
  display: inline-block;
      font-family: TeX Gyre Heros,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul>
<li class="breadcr" >1</li>
<li class="active breadcr">2</li>
<li class="breadcr">3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="sub">
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 25px;"><b>File or link</b></li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 53px;"><b>Category</b></li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 50px;"><b>Comments</b><li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I tried your approach guys and the lines vanished: https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Form/index03.html

Comment: Do you have any other suggestions @Andy Tschierch and @priya_singh?

Comment: Look at my answer, you just have to use the z-index in ul instead of li.

Comment: I tried to use z-index in ul instead of li and the lines are above circles instead of below: https://ewelinawoloszyn.github.io/Form/index03.html

Comment: @neko now li.breadcr::before {z-index: -1} add this only. you will get what you needed

Comment: Just add `z-index: -1` to :before.

Comment: after all your property just add this z-index: -1; try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

```css
li.breadcr {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: #0095c4;
  margin: 0 3em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
li.breadcr::before {
  content: '' !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  top: .9em !important;
  left: -8em !important;
  width: 10em !important;
  height: .2em !important;
  background: #0095c4 !important;
  z-index: -1 !important;
}
li.breadcr:first-child::before {
  display: none !important;
}
.active {
  background: #0095c4;
}
.active ~ li.breadcr {
  background: #badae4 !important;
}
.active ~ li.breadcr::before {
  background: #badae4 !important;
}
ul.sub {
  list-style: none;
}
li.sub02 {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: TeX Gyre Heros, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="breadcr">1</li>
  <li class="active breadcr">2</li>
  <li class="breadcr">3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub">
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 25px;"><b>File or link</b>
  </li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 53px;"><b>Category</b>
  </li>
  <li class="sub02" style="margin-left: 50px;"><b>Comments</b>
    <li>
</ul>
```